# jQuery AJAX POST not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, client-side

I am trying to post some data from one local asp.net mvc site to another but am unable to do so. I execute the following post on site A

```
// tried this and it didn't work      
//$.post("http://localhost/PlatformPortal/Buyers/Account/SignIn",
//{sign:authHeader})

// Currently trying this                  
    $.ajax({
             url: "http://localhost/PlatformPortal/Buyers/Account/SignIn",
             data: authHeader,
             type: "POST",
             success: function() { alert('Success!'); }
          })
```

I expected the POST "SignIn" action in the AccountController for SiteB to be hit, but it isn't. However, I do get the "Success!" popup message when I execute the post by clicking the link that the jquery snippet pasted above is wired to. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $.ajax() uses XMLHttpRequest, it is subject to XHR's cross-domain restriction.

Are your SiteA and SiteB on different hosts/ports?  If so, you're seeing the expected behavior.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for getting back to me.Currently for testing purposes both my sites are on my local dev. box (localhost). So they are something like http://localhost/SiteA and http://localhost/SiteB

Comment: If you run Fiddler to monitor the traffic, are you seeing anything returned from SiteB?

Comment: I get a perfect return (200) from the server in Fiddler with the following info.

Uri - http://localhost/PlatformPortal/Buyers/Account/SignIn
RequestHeaders
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 0
Data: Test

Is the "data" variable that is part of the jQuery ajax syntax the POST body or the header ?

Comment: My bad, it was in fact working fine, a Visual Studio was unable to catch the post on account of a pending restart and it couldn't load the debugging symbols right. The post is working just fine. Thanks a ton for your patience.